# How to completely disable the mouse/finger interaction for highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I searched through the docs but could not find a post discussing this.

I'm currently working on a project which's both available for mobile and pc browsers. Since the screen on iPhone is very small, I'd like to disable highcharts interaction on it (the interaction would fail me even scroll down the page).

I would like to ask whether there's any parameter like "hasInteraction:false".

Thanks for any kind of tips!

update:

I tried this code from Ricardo Lohmann and it's working to disable the mouse tracking:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
}
```

But on mobile device it's still blocking my finger scrolling down. I searched on Google and found a post: http://blog.rafael.jp/post/2958719820/div-mouseenabled-false but still not working (to allow the chart not blocking my finger scroll)

Comment: By interaction what do you mean exactly? Do you mean you don't want the chart to be clickable and don't wanna see any tooltips etc. If so I don't think there is a global parameter for disabling that. You have to disable those properties through chart options manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm looking for a solution to this as well.
More precisely, I'd like to enable page scrolling even when finger starts dragging on the chart. I'd still like that a touch on a data point opens up a tooltip.

You might be interested in this commit from v3.0.4 ["Added new option, tooltip.followTouchMove ..."](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/49e18e017f02c107714f3aae316dc1021bdbf288). <strike>I still have to try that</strike>. I tried that on iPhone simulator and it works:

Somewhere in your HTML page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.highcharts.com/3.0.1/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Later on, when you create the chart in your JavaScript code:

```js
$('#chartdiv').highcharts({
    chart : {
        type : 'line',  // e.g. for a line chart
        zoomType: null,  // this is already the default, it's just to stress what's said in commit comments and make code "speak"
    },
    tooltip: {
        followPointer: false,  // this is already the default, it's just to stress what's said in commit comments and make code "speak"
        followTouchMove: false,  // this is already the default, it's just to stress what's said in commit comments and make code "speak"
    },
    // other options...
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/CDJVU/)

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, but the chart is still preventing the mouse tracking on mobile devices, at least for my iPhone. Do you know there's any other settings that I should adjust?

Answer (score -1):

```
       plotOptions: {
           <your type of chart, for example "spline">: {
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
```

May fix your problem

Comment: Same answer as Ricardo gave more than 4 years earlier.